# Negation of a quantified statement about odd integers

Tags: logic, quantifiers, parity

I've been trying to negate the following statement using quantifiers, but I can't seem to totally make sense of it (let $n$ be an integer.):

- There exists an odd integer $k$ such that $n=2k$.

One of my attempts at negation was, "For all integers $k$, $n=2k$ implies that $k$ is even," though I'm not entirely sure of this. Even if it is, it's still not the most practical negation for proof purposes. I was told by my professor that the negation of the original statement is, "$n$ is odd or $n=2k$ for even $k$." I'm not sure how to get to that statement using purely symbolic logic and quantifiers. Can anybody show this using quantified statements?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For starters, did you write the original statement using quantifiers? It will be easier to negate it then. Second, do you know how negations of quantified statements work? More specifically: what is a negation of $\forall x:P(x)$ and what is a negation of $\exists x:P(x)$?

Comment: So I know that the negation of $\forall x :P(x)$ is $\exists x : \neg P(x)$ and the negation of $\exists x : P(x)$ is $\forall x :\neg P(x)$. Perhaps one way to write the original statement is $\exists k \in Z$, $(2 \nmid k) \land (n = 2k)$. But negating this particular statement is somewhat tricky.

Comment: I tried negating by using DeMorgan's Laws on the statement, obtaining, "For all integers k, $2 \mid k$ or $n \neq 2k$." I believe this is to say that "n is odd or k is even", but that's not exactly what my professor's negation says, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the negation of the original statement is not *logically* equivalent of the statement from your professor. You need to add all kinds of basic arithmetical truths (such as that every integer is either even or odd) in order to infer your professor's statement from it ... These are arithmetical truths, but not logical truths. So if you try to do this using pure logic, it's not going to work.

The best you can do is to indeed define a bunch of axioms about integers, defining the numbers 1 and 2, defining addition and multiplication, and defining even and odd. Then, you should be able to derive the following statement from those axioms as a theorem:

$\forall n (\neg \exists k (Odd(k) \land n =2k) \leftrightarrow (Odd(n) \lor \exists k (Even(k) \land n =2k)))$

Or, if you don't like to use $Even$ and $Odd$ predicates:

$\forall n (\neg \exists k (\exists m \: k =2m+1 \land n=2k) \leftrightarrow (\exists m \: n=2m+1 \lor \exists k (\exists m \: k=2m \land n=2k)))$

These biconditionals show that *arithmetically* the two claims are the same (just as saying that 'integer n is even' is arithmetically the same claim as 'integer n is not odd'), but the two claims are not *logically* the same!

Comment: This is an interesting insight that clarifies things a good deal. Thank you! There's still something uncomfortable and strange about those quantified statements to me, but I'll wrestle with them for a bit longer.